# Replace Windows 7 beep sound

Tags: windows-7

How can one replace the beep sound that Windows 7 makes when for example one types `echo`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>,<kbd>Enter</kbd> in a cmd window?

(There is no option to change it in the System Sounds GUI.)

Comment: I tried that with headphones on to see what you were talking about and almost had a heart attack.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the System Beep? If so:

- Right click the Computer icon located on your desktop, or in the Start Menu. Then, select Manage from the drop-down list *or* open the Run dialog and type compmgmt.msc *or* search for Computer Management.
- From the Computer Management window, go to 'System tools -> Device Manager'.
- In the View menu dropdown select 'Show hidden devices'.
- Expand the list of devices under 'Non-Plug and Play Drivers' and select Beep.
- Right click the 'Beep' item and select Properties.

  - In the 'Beep Properties' window, go to the Driver tab.
- In the Startup section, scroll down the Type list, select Disable and click the OK button.

*Now restart your computer.*

After a restart, the system beep should be disabled.
Original source with images [here](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-disable-system-beep-windows-7).

Comment: I don't want to disable it. I want to change the sound it makes.

Comment: @Kalmi Sorry! Misread the question. I can't find a way of changing the actual sound online, although there probably is a solution available.